# Web service consumer SOAP version is showing error by default

Tags: mule-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4, mule-connector

I am trying to configure a SOAP service using web service consumer, as soon as I click on new configuration in the connector configuration, I see SOAP version column is turning into error and when I hover on it, it is showing some tooling related error and when i check my tooling stats in preferences, it shows in running state.
My studio version is 7.11.1

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the version of the Web Service Consumer connector? Can you try again with Studio 7.12? What version of Java uses the project? Please try to copy the complete error from the tooltip and add it in your question.

Comment: @aled, I have upgraded the studio to 7.12 version, java version is 1.8 and I am using 1.6.10 version of the web service consumer but still getting the same issue on Soap version, I try to capture maximum of the error in tooltip(added second screen shot in the main post) because it seems to be very big and I could not see complete error in one-go and there is no scrolling option. please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: Can you click on the tooltip and copy the text? Usually it is possible to do it in Studio.

Comment: @aled, no it is not allowing as soon as I lift the mouse from the error, it is disappearing.

Comment: What I observe is while trying to create configuration in web service consumer, it is trying to load metadata and afterwards it is showing the error in SOAP version, my assumption is some how it is unable to download the metadata properly for the web service consumer module, please let me know if anything can be done in this part.

Answer (score 0):

The information is not complete to identify the root cause. Having said that it is possible that the error is happening when the Web Service Consumer connector is trying to download the WSDL if the access is restricted in some way. For example if the server has whitelisted the IPs of authorized clients, or there is an access restriction in your network, or some other permission issue.

In that case you may resolve the issue if you can download the WSDL locally and add it to the application in the src/main/resources folder, and reference it by the file name (with no path) instead of an URL.